# AWS lambda function integration with snowflake connectivity error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-api-gateway, python-3.9

I am working on building python code in lambda function to receive event notifications from webhooks and load the extract payload data into snowflake but before that I was testing to check snowflake connections in lambda code whether i am getting response back or not.

Here is sample code:
import json
import snowflake.connector

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='xxxx',
password='xxxx',
account='https://xxxx.snowflakecomputing.com'
)
cs = ctx.cursor()
cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
one_row = cs.fetchone()
cs.close()
ctx.close()
```

## Define the lambda_handler function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
return {
'statusCode': 200,
'current Snowflake version': one_row[0]
}
```

Error: `your text`
"errorMessage": "250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting",

## "errorType": "OperationalError",

I have tried to check snowflake integration with lambda function and get the response back but getting an error.

Comment: I modified account parameter:
    account='xxxxx.us-west-2',     (modified part)

Now i am getting new error:

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-09-11T19:56:49.596Z c16f4054-035a-44fd-94d6-448ba58e36e3 Task timed out after 60.10 seconds"
}